# Messages to flag Async Task has started and Completed

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

I have an Async task in my app that will trigger some things when it is finished, but this causes some issues is the phone goes to sleep. I need a way to know, when I come back to the app, that the Async Task did it's work. I have looked around quite a bit about this but I think my problem is I don't even know where to begin. Any information is helpful.

Comment: How long does this AsyncTask run? Maybe you'd be better off with a Service?

Comment: It does run for quite a bit. I think my problem is that, in my case, I am dismissing a dialog fragment after the Async is finished. So when I come back (whether it is sleeping or the home button has been pressed and the user comes back to the app) it's mixed up because I attempt to dismiss the fragment dialog.

Comment: You'd better look into using a service then. You can send a broadcast to the foreground activity to dismiss that dialog, and check whether the service has completed in the Activity's `onResume`.

Comment: Why not use a service and broadcast a message when done so you know the activity finished? Implement a local broadcast manager in your activity to receive the results.

Comment: And can I receive the results even if my Activity is paused, and I come back to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing the dialog fragment in your onpause method. And check if your layout is visible to your users in your AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method like this:

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
root.isShown()//check if the layout is visible to user
```